# Android studio,Is it possible to use Bluetooth on the emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

Is it possible to use Bluetooth on the emulator?

I don't like using a cell phone to test... my PC uses a bluetooh adapter, is it possible to access it on the emulator and make it work with the emulator without problems?

I hope to use bluetooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator does not provide emulation for the following hardware

- Bluetooth
- NFC
- SD card insert/eject
- Device-attached headphones
- USB

So, if your application under test uses Bluetooth, you need a physical device.